# How to add a new sub field in an object in existing Json Array in Vb.Net?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to write simple Json Array. 
I m bit rusty with this Json as I have just started learning it with **Vb.Net** and Using **NewtonSoft.Json** Library

Sorry if there is something wrong in question. As I said that I just started Json so please advice to rectify.

Old Json:

```
[{
    "YEAR": "2018-2019",
    "COMPNO": "1",
    "TYPE": "SAL",
    "Field1": false  
  },
  {
    "YEAR": "2018-2019",
    "COMPNO": "2",
    "TYPE": "PUR",
    "Field1": false
  }]
```

I want a field to add in the object like

New Json:

```
[{
    "YEAR": "2018-2019",
    "COMPNO": "1",
    "TYPE": "SAL",
    "Field1": false,
    "Field2": false   '-----------------------Something Like this
  },
  {
    "YEAR": "2018-2019",
    "COMPNO": "2",
    "TYPE": "PUR",
    "Field1": false,
    "Field2": false     '--------------In every object if possible.
  }]
```

My Json is simple without groups.
I know how to add a new Object inside the Jarray but I want to add a field

How can I achieve this task?

 P.S I am using **Newtonsoft.JSON** libraries.

Comment: If you add a comma between `"Field1": false` and `"Field2": false`, that's a vaid JSON. Are you asking how to modify the JSON or the classes that store/handle it?

Comment: We would need to see how you are currently doing it.

Comment: @Jimi My mistake , I forgot a ',' but I hope you understood what I wanted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit switched to VB

```
   Dim initialJson = "[{" & vbCrLf & "    ""YEAR"": ""2018-2019""," & vbCrLf & "    ""COMPNO"": ""1""," & vbCrLf & "    ""TYPE"": ""SAL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""Field1"": false  " & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""YEAR"": ""2018-2019""," & vbCrLf & "    ""COMPNO"": ""2""," & vbCrLf & "    ""TYPE"": ""PUR""," & vbCrLf & "    ""Field1"": false" & vbCrLf & "  }]"

    Dim array = JArray.Parse(initialJson)
    For Each item In array
        item("Field2") = False
    Next

    Dim Result = array
```

If you are creating that json I would suggest doing it before you create it but if you just need to update that array.

```
        var initialJson = "[{\r\n    \"YEAR\": \"2018-2019\",\r\n    \"COMPNO\": \"1\",\r\n    \"TYPE\": \"SAL\",\r\n    \"Field1\": false  \r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"YEAR\": \"2018-2019\",\r\n    \"COMPNO\": \"2\",\r\n    \"TYPE\": \"PUR\",\r\n    \"Field1\": false\r\n  }]";

        var array = JArray.Parse(initialJson);

        array.ToList().ForEach(item => item["Field2"] = false);

        var result = array;
```

Comment: Good catch will change that real quick.

Comment: Don't forget to the `ToString()` to convert the `JArray` back to JSON

Comment: @RyanSchlueter The answer I got from you is real quick.
Thanx Again. Just one thing I want to ask. Can you tell me code to check if `Field2` exists in each item. Something like `if not Field2 exists then item("Field2") = False end if`

Comment: I believe there is a contains key method or you can check if item("Field2") = =null before setting it. If that doesn't work I can look when get to computer

Comment: Your assumptions are also right :). I don't know about 'contains' keyword but I coded something like this in Vb.net --> `if item(Field2) = nothing then item(Field2) = False` and it worked... Thanx a lot. @RyanSchlueter

Comment: vb.net don't have == operator. Its == is = and null is nothing. @RyanSchlueter